# How to compare user input to a column data in csv file?

Tags: ios, xcode, csv

I use the following code, but it only checks first column in first row. But I want to check first column of all rows in a csv file. Please help

```
- (void) SearchStudent 

{ 
    NSArray *DocumentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //I upload the csv file to documents folder of the app through itunes
    NSString *DocumentDirectory = [DocumentPath objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *FullPath = [DocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"example.csv"]]; 
    NSString * pstrCSVFile= [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:FullPath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL]; 
    NSArray * paRowsOfCSVFile= [pstrCSVFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; 
    NSArray *paColumnsOfRow; 

    NSString *pstrFirstColumn;    
    for(NSString * pstrRow in paRowsOfCSVFile)  
    {  
        paColumnsOfRow= [pstrRow componentsSeparatedByString:@","];  
        pstrFirstColumn= [paColumnsOfRow objectAtIndex:0]; 
        if([pstrFirstColumn localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:GWIDText.text] == NSOrderedSame) 
        { 
            UIAlertView *alertingFileName = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];  
            [alertingFileName show]; 
            break; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            UIAlertView *alertingFileName1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Not Found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]; 
            [alertingFileName1 show]; 
        } 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`paColumnsOfRow` contain all rows.